# Group by and count in Sequelize

Tags: express, group-by, count, sequelize.js

I have a table named Matches in PosGres, which has columns match_name, room_full, game_completed, createdAt. I want to count the room_full and game_completed grouped by createdAt(only the year,month and day not with the time).
I have records grouped by created_at with only the year, month and day but unable to get counts of room_full and game_completed. Here is my code.

```
Match.findAll({paranoid:false,
        where: {
              createdAt: {
                [Op.gte]: moment().subtract(7, 'days').toDate()
              }
            },
        group: [db.sequelize.fn('date_trunc', 'day', db.sequelize.col('createdAt'))]
      })
```

Can anyone please help me with this. I want it to represent in a line chart. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should use [Sequelize functions](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js%7ESequelize.html#static-method-fn) :

```
Match.findAll({
  paranoid: false,
  group: [db.sequelize.fn('date_trunc', 'day', db.sequelize.col('createdAt'))],
  attributes: [
    db.sequelize.fn('date_trunc', 'day', db.sequelize.col('createdAt')),
    [db.sequelize.fn('COUNT', 'game_completed'), 'game_completed_count'],
    [db.sequelize.fn('COUNT', 'room_full'), 'room_full_count']
  ],
  where: {
    createdAt: {
      [Op.gte]: moment().subtract(7, 'days').toDate()
    }
  },
})
```

Or alternatively use `SUM` instead of `COUNT` if your two fields represents values instead of flags.

Comment: How can I get createdAt also in the response? @T4ze

Comment: This query should output you the truncated version of your createdAt field. Is this what you’re looking for? You can also add any additional fields you want in the `attributes` array.

Comment: I am getting only the counts of room_full and game_completed but not the createdAt. @T4ze